# How do I programmatically execute a carriage return in bash?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, iterm2, iterm

My main file is main.sh:

```
cd a_folder
echo "executing another script"
source anotherscript.sh
cd ..
#some other operations.
```

anotherscript.sh:

```
pause(){
   read -p "$*"
}
echo "enter a number: "
read number
#some operation
pause "Press enter to continue..."
```

I wanted to skip the pause command. But when I do:

```
echo "/n" | source anotherscript.sh
```

It doesn't allow to enter the number. I want the "/n" to occur so that I allow the user to enter a number but skip the pause statement.

PS: can't do any changes in anotherscript.sh. All changes to be done in main.sh.

Comment: What did you mean by `I wanted to skip the pause command`? Could you elaborate more? Is pause a user defined function? do you want to bypass by modifying the `main.sh`

Comment: thats right, @Inian. Edited my description accordingly.

Comment: To output a carriage return, instead of `echo "/n"`, you need to do `printf "\n"`, with a backslash and not a slash, or even better just `echo` without arguments.

Comment: Consider `source anotherscript.sh < <(printf '\n' '1234' '')`, which avoids needing a pipeline, which [causes the code to be `source`ed in a completely different shell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), thus defeating the point of using `source` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo | source anotherscript.sh
```

Comment: The problem is that the OP expects the script they're sourcing to operate in the context of their currently running shell (variables to be set, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work, because the script to be sourced expectes *two* lines from stdin: First a line containing a number, then an empty line (which is doing the pause). Hence you would have to feed two lines, the number and the empty line, to the script. If you still want to get the number from your own stdin, you would have to use a `read` command before:

```
echo "executing another script"
echo "enter a number: "
read number
printf "$number\n\n" | source anotherscript.sh
```

But this still has some danger lurking: The source command is executed in a subshell; hence, any changes in the environment performed by `anotherscript.sh` won't be visible in your shell.

A workaround would be to be to put the number-reading logic outside of main.sh:

```
# This is script supermain.sh
echo "executing another script"
echo "enter a number: "
read number
printf "$number\n\n"|bash main.sh
```

where in main.sh, you simply keep your `source anotherscript.sh` without any piping.

Answer (score 0):

As user1934428 comments, the `bash` pipeline causes the cascading
commands to be executed in subshells and the variable modifications
there are not reflected in the current process.
To change this behavior, you can set `lastpipe` with `shopt` builtin.
Then `bash` changes the job control so that the last command in the
pipeline is executed in the current shell (as `tsch` does).

Then would you please try:

**main_sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s lastpipe               # this changes the job control
read -p "enter a number: " x    # ask for the number in main_sh instead
cd a_folder
echo "executing another script"
echo "$x" | source anotherscript.sh > /dev/null
                                # anotherscript.sh is executed in the current process
                                # unnecessary messages are redirected to /dev/null
cd ..
echo "you entered $number"      # check the result
#some other operations.
```

which will properly print the value of `number`.

Alternatively you can also say as:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "enter a number: " x
cd a_folder
echo "executing another script"
source anotherscript.sh <<< "$x" > /dev/null
cd ..
echo "you entered $number"
#some other operations.
```